# How to make Python linting work in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I assumed that installing the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) would automatically support linting. For Javascript I get the error squiggles, but no luck with Python.

I think it is supposed to work out of the box, but it didn't. These are the settings for the workspace:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/mark/.pyenv/versions/ve381/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of pylint not to work was a .pylintrc file which required a library that wasn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's enabled by default, there's the extra step that you have to select the linter (and probably install it if you haven't already).

If you click on the gear at the bottom left, and select Command Palette, then in the text box that appears at the top of the window, type "linter" and "Python: Select Linter" should come up.

A default linter is pylint. If you select it and it's not installed, you will be prompted to install it. When I did so, I ran into problems on my Windows OS with SSL certificates or something like that (I would get the same error if trying to install from CMD prompt). So I went to the anaconda prompt I was using and installed it there in my conda environment and that worked.

But if it works for you to install from inside Code, then you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did all that and don't get any errors, but the code in the editor is not linted. Do you actually get the error squiggles? What linter do you use?